# Android adds item on back stack even when its not specified

Tags: android

I have a fragment, called SplashScreenFragment. He is adding in onCreate of application with call of

```
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.host_root, SplashScreen())
        .commit()
```

After 3 seconds I replacing this fragment with another one, calling

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.host_root, fragment, fragment.tag())
.addToBackStack(null)
.commit()
```

But when I'm pressing back button, Im returning to my SplashScreen, but I wanna exit an application. How to fix this?

Comment: try to remove .addTobackStack(null) when you are calling the new fragment

Answer (score 1):

Remove "**.addToBackStack(null)**"

This code means your fragment to add backstack.

[addToBackStack(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

If this is not critical for you, you can override the onBackPressed call and do nothing

Comment: Unfortunately, its allready overriden in MainActivity and its makes popbackstack() on a fragments. So I need other workaround

Comment: fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); try it

Comment: Strange try to put .popBackStack (null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE) instead of .addToBackStack (null)